# Change logo (and other icon.svg) when theme is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie trying to build a portfolio page starting from mobile-first.
I just learned about integrating the prefers-colour-scheme media query, but before adding that, I would like to give the user a choice to toggle between dark/light modes in my webpage.
I have added a javascript which would do that.

**I want my logo and icons.svg to also change when I toggle between themes**

You could have a look at my codepen which is linked.

You can test the problem by following these steps:

1. Go to the menu --> click to toggle to the light mode
2. The logo changes, BUT it won't change back when I toggle back to dark mode.
3. I also have the same problem when I click on the logo, while in light mode, it changes to the default dark mode logo.

I am assuming if I know how to get this working for just the logo, I can use the same technique with other icons too.

How do I get this to work?

[Check the codepen link to my problem](https://codepen.io/headofclowns/pen/eYJbbXp)
Apologies for the long and disturbing base64 data for my svg in my codepen, I didn't know what else to do.

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
  }
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);



/*This is to store the light or dark mode preferences for future visits*/

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //add this
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light'); //add this
  }
}

/*to check for saved preferences on load of the site*/

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;

if (currentTheme) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);

  if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
  }
}

function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('mylogo');
  if (image.src.match("images/LOGO_SN_over_black.svg")) {
    image.src = "images/LOGO_SN.svg";
  } else {
    image.src = "images/LOGO_SN.svg";
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --background-color: #262626;
  --mainfontcolor: #f7f7f2;
  --hightlightcolor: #01BAEF;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --background-color: #f7f7f2;
  --mainfontcolor: #262626;
  --hightlightcolor: #01BAEF;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/*Navigation panel*/

.logo-header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2em;
  left: 2em;
  max-width: 3em;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 9999;
}

header {
  background: var(--background-color);
  height: 5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: calc(100vw);
  z-index: 90;
}


/*menu bar styles start here*/

.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5em;
  right: 3.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 4.2em;
  height: 2em;
  z-index: 100;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.8em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*hamburger line */

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: none;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1em;
  background-color: var(--mainfontcolor);
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: -0.6em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.1em;
  background-color: var(--mainfontcolor);
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div:after {
  top: 0.6em;
}


/*toggle animate*/

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}


/* Turns Lines Into X */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked+.hamburger>div:after {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/* Rotate On Hover When Checked */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover+.hamburger>div {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}


/* To Show the Menu */

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked~.menu>div>div {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0.3s;
}

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100vw);
  height: calc(100vh);
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  border-radius: 0%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: none;
  flex: none;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: calc(100vw);
  max-height: calc(100vh);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  color: var(--mainfontcolor);
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 0.8em;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li>a {
  color: var(--mainfontcolor);
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
}


/*Main page content*/

.mainpage-container {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: var(--mainfontcolor);
  margin-top: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.mainpage-section2 {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.content-image {
  width: calc(100vw);
  height: calc(95vh);
  background-image: url('https://st.depositphotos.com/1695366/1398/v/450/depositphotos_13980191-stock-illustration-cartoon-woman-writing-new-years.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainpage-text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mainpage-text h1 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: var(--mainfontcolor);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-top: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.mainpage-text h2 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: var(--mainfontcolor);
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

.mainpage-text p {
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.contact-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: var(--mainfontcolor);
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  position: relative;
}

.mainpage-text p :hover {
  color: var(--hightlightcolor);
}

.contact-link::before {
  border-top: 0.05em dotted var(--mainfontcolor);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 1.2em;
  left: 0;
}


/*toggle to dark or light mode*/

.theme-switch-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.theme-switch-wrapper em {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.theme-switch-wrapper img {
  width: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
}

.theme-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  width: 2.6em;
}

.theme-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  background-color: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: 0.15em;
  content: "";
  height: 1.2em;
  left: 0.16em;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 1.2em;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #01BAEF;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="logo-header">
        <a href="index.html"><img id="mylogo" src="image-of-logo-for darktheme"></a>
      </div>



      <div class="menu-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                  <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
                    <em><img src="moon-dark"></em>
                    <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="changeImage()" value="Change" id="checkbox" />
                                            <div class="slider round"></div>
                                        </label>
                    <em><img src="sun-light"></em>
                  </div>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>

    <div class="mainpage-container">
      <section class="mainpage-section1">
        <div class="content-image"></div>
      </section>
      <section class="mainpage-section2">
        <div class="mainpage-text">
          <div>
            <h1>I'M A <br>MATERIAL SCIENTIST<br> - PHYSICIST.</h1>
            <h2>(With speciality in nanotechnology, materials science and a Ph.D. in physics.) </h2><br>
            <h2>I develop efficient science communication strategies and create content for science blogs, magazines and, radio/tv shows.</h2>
            <p><a class="contact-link" href="contact.html">Get in touch with me.</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

  </main>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem #1

The problem is that you disable both logos at the first time the user visits the page, since the default is dark theme you should change:

```css
#mylogo .darktheme,
#mylogo .lighttheme {
    display: none;
}
```

into:

```css
#mylogo .lighttheme {
    display: none;
}
```

And now the darktheme logo should be displayed the first time the user visits the page.

## Problem #2

You don't set the image to the light theme one when theme was set to light in the internal storage, so you can insert this after line 36:

```js
if (currentTheme === 'light') {
    changeImage()
}
```

Because dark theme logo is the default one you only have to switch it when the theme was set to light.

## Problem #1

I've spotted the mistake, in this part of code of javascript:

```js
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById('mylogo');
    if (image.src.match("images/LOGO_SN_over_black.svg")) {
        image.src = "images/LOGO_SN.svg";
    } else {
        image.src = "images/LOGO_SN.svg";
    }
}
```

If the logo is the logo over dark you change it to the normal logo, and if it isn't you change it to the normal logo again, so when you toggle the logo you always put the normal logo.
To solve it, you need to change the code and make that when the logo isn't the over black logo, you change it to the over black logo. For example like this:

```
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById('mylogo');
    if (image.src.match("images/LOGO_SN_over_black.svg")) {
        image.src = "images/LOGO_SN.svg";
    } else {
        image.src = "images/LOGO_SN_over_black.svg";
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct! I changed it. but it still doesn't solve the entire problem. I get to toggle back and forth, but if I click on an internal link, it falls back to the default logo image.

Comment: @fullfledgedclown
I've updated the answer to include the solution for the second problem.

Comment: I have now updated my attempt at having the theme switch along with the logo change using just CSS. But the new problem is that when a user open the page for the very first time without any chache/local storage, no logo appears as a default. How do I solve this?  [link] https://codepen.io/headofclowns/pen/XWXGVzQ

Comment: Maybe you should add contributions in different questions to diferent files, because this way, is harder to help.
@fullfledgedclown I've updated the answer to include the solution for the third problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be more complex than it needs to be. Possibly you could find a CSS only solution by adding both light and dark logos:

```
<span id="mylogo">
  <img class="darktheme" src="...">
  <img class="lighttheme" src="...">
</span>
```

Then style accordingly

```
#mylogo .darktheme,
#mylogo .lighttheme {
 display: none;
}

[data-theme="dark"] #mylogo .darktheme {
  display: inline;
}

[data-theme="light"] #mylogo .lighttheme {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Here is the updated version of my attempt to use the theme switching using just CSS just like you suggested. The icons change with the theme, but when I open the link without local storage,  I do not see a default logo. [link] https://codepen.io/headofclowns/pen/XWXGVzQ

Comment: Thats interesting. I think you might have to set a default, e.g. light. Upon that you would have to check the localStorage to find the stored value and update accordingly

Comment: That's the best solution in my opinion! Clean and no JS.